# More efficient way to check if Asset field is blank within Matrix

Tags: assets, matrix, playa

Need to display if a Asset field within a Matrix field has a file or not.  While this works, the overhead is really high.  Is there a way to write this with less overhead?  Based on the EE template debug, here's the simplified snippet that causes the most lag:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
       {exp:playa:parents}
          {if '{matrixfield search:assetfield="not IS_EMPTY"}{row_id}{/matrixfield}'!=""}
             I'm not blank!
          {/if}
       {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Using the search+row_id is most efficient way I've tested to write it, but it's still some 2k queries/8sec vs the 100/.xsec the site normally has.  With the Asset in Matrix, in Playa, in Entries I would expect some additional processing time.  Open to any ideas to try!

Comment: Could you not just check to see if the matrix cell is empty by using the matrix column name rather than actually checking the Asset field within the Matrix field?

Comment: The column name calls the Assets plugin. {matrixfield}{asset_column_name}{/matrixfield} had even more overhead.  Unless there's a way to ask for that column without using the cell name itself.  Is that what you were suggesting or did I miss something?

Comment: Blair, I think I'm confused as well.  Have you tried {matrixfield}{if asset_column_name != ""}{row_id}{/if}{/matrixfield}?

Comment: I didn't know that was a tag.  Where's the docs for it and I'll give it a shot?

Comment: Ok, sorry, brain fail.  The asset_column_name (what I called assetfield, which is really called audio_file) used in that way gives about another 300 queries.  I did try that.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - did you ever discover a good way to get around the n+1 problem?